# Wordpress JSON API remove posts from a specific category

Tags: plugins, categories, api, json

I have installed Wordpress JSON APi plugin, the idea what I want to do is to retrieve all posts from a websites except a specific category for example with ID: 434.

I need all posts except from this category.

The query is like this example: www.example.com/?json=1&count=300

I have changed something in code but it removes the details of categories, not posts.

```
if ($category->id == 434 && $category->slug == 'archive') {
// Skip the 'archive' category
continue;
        }
```

How it is possible, please help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. You have to go to the folder controllers/core.php and there you have to change the function get_recent_posts().
You have to add this code to remove categories that you don't want:

```
public function get_recent_posts() {
global $json_api;

// get all the categories from the database
        $cats = get_categories(); 

            // loop through the categries
            foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                // setup the cateogory ID
                $cat_id = $cat->term_id;

                // create a custom wordpress query
                query_posts("cat=-434,-22837,-13571,-1,-18,-17385");
                // start the wordpress loop!

                while (have_posts()) {
                $posts = $json_api->introspector->get_posts();  
                return $this->posts_result($posts);
                }
           } 

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, please mark this as the accepted answer.